# DFS: File randomly missing?

Tags: windows-server-2008, dfs

We have a DFS installed on two different servers.

Running health reports finds no errors and generally everything seems OK, but:

1. On some computers, files will be saved on a DFS folder randomly, but will not actually appear on other computers or physically on the server. Sometimes they will appear on other computers if logged under the same user, but other users, including the admin, would not be able to see them.
2. Other files, have just disappeared.

Update:

```
DFS Replication Health Report (Show All) 

Data collected on: 15 December 2015 at 11:43:32 (GMT0:00) 
Replication Group: TeachingData (NSNET.NET) 
Reference member: SRV-FS02 (srv-fs02.nsnet.net) 
Server scope: Selected 2 of 2 servers 
DFS Replication bandwidth savings: 0.00% 
Server health:  Servers with no errors or warnings (1)  Servers unavailable for reporting (0)   
Servers with DFS Replication errors (1)  Servers with DFS Replication warnings (1) 



Report Loading. Please wait . . .
ERRORS  (1 server with errors)(Show All)
SRV-FS02   (1 error)    (View Server Details) 
Cannot access the local WMI repository.  


WARNINGS  (1 server with warnings)(Show All)
SRV-FS02   (1 warning)    (View Server Details) 
Reference member returned no replicated folders.  


SERVERS UNAVAILABLE FOR REPORTING  (All servers reporting)
SERVER DETAILS  (2 servers)(Show All)
Rendering content. Please wait . . .
SRV-FS02(Show All)
DNS name: srv-fs02.nsnet.net 
Domain name: NSNET.NET 
Reference domain controller: -- 
IP address: fe80::a888:789d:b82:1354%16,192.168.0.67 
Site: Default-First-Site-Name 
Time zone: (GMT0:00) 
ERRORS (There is 1 error to report)

Cannot access the local WMI repository.  
Affected replicated folders: All replicated folders on this server. 
Description: Due to the following error, the DFS Replication reporting mechanism cannot access the WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) namespace to retrieve certain reporting information. Error ID: 0x80041002.  
Last occurred: 15 December 2015 at 11:43:32 (GMT0:00) 
Suggested action: For information about troubleshooting WMI errors, see WMI help.  

WARNINGS (There is 1 warning to report)

Reference member returned no replicated folders.  
Description: Backlog calculations cannot be performed because the reference member returned zero replicated folders.  
Last occurred: 15 December 2015 at 11:43:33 (GMT0:00) 
Suggested action: For information about troubleshooting backlog problems, see The Microsoft Web Site.
```

Comment: `will not appear physically on the server` Where is the computer located, that created the file? Is it connected via LAN, or via WAN? The only thing that comes to my mind that may be responsible is that the file is created in the offline cache, hence not physically stored on the file server yet.

Comment: When I say physically I meant if I am physically on the server and through the shared folder. It's all connected via LAN. How can I see if it's still in cache or see why it's not connected ?

Comment: We need more information. Affected namespaces. Affected dfs-folders. Folder targets. Replication? etc. How is DFS and DFS-R configured. In detail.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Thanks for helping ! I've attached a screenshot. The "common" one is the one affected, as well as (I am guessing) the "common" namespace. Here's the image: http://imgur.com/TbaX1wA

Comment: Also seem to get error 13575 in event viewer. Not sure if it's related or even how to fix it :/

Comment: Does the issue with the missing file occur, if you omit DFS and write directly to the shared folder?

Comment: I am not sure, since it's completely random :)

Comment: Here's what I found so far:

Comment: The DFS Replication service is stopping communication with partner SRV-DC02 for replication group Domain System Volume due to an error. The service will retry the connection periodically. 

Additional Information: 
Error: 9036 (Paused for backup or restore) 
Connection ID: D6A3F326-9FD2-43C1-9610-907E622FD59E 
Replication Group ID: B33E6706-5442-43ED-B4BA-82199A9EC515

Comment: 2. Not sure what this is and how to fix it :
This domain controller has migrated to using the DFS Replication service to replicate the SYSVOL share. Use of the File Replication Service for replication of non-SYSVOL content sets has been deprecated and therefore, the service has been stopped. The DFS Replication service is recommended for replication of folders, the SYSVOL share on domain controllers and DFS link targets.

Comment: On the other server: (Using WMIdiag)
 3. 27730 11:10:40 (0) ** ERROR: WMIDiag detected issues that could prevent WMI to work properly!.  Check 'C:\USERS\ADMIN\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\WMIDIAG-V2.2_2K12R2.SRV.RTM.64_SRV-FS02_2015.12.15_11.01.03.LOG' for details.

Comment: Some things that come to my mind: 1) File gets written to target #1 and is invisible to other computers because they access target #2 until replication runs. 2a) It's a [replication issue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732802.aspx). 2b) It's an issue with the replication of certain files. Check [Staging folders and Conflict and Deleted folders](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782648%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)3) It has nothing to do with DFS because it can be reproduced when directly accessing the shared folder.

Comment: Jason, could you update the question with your error information? It's easier to read when properly formatted. And it would help other people with the same error to find a solution. Serverfault aims to be a Q&A site and less to be a support forum. So when you ask questions and give additional information, keep in mind, that we do it for all the other admins with same and similar issues. Thank you. :) If WMI is broken that could cause DFS issues, afaik. I'll look into that later.

Comment: Sure. I'm not too sure how to check for errors, that's why.

Comment: Just updated ! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33004/discussion-between-daniel-and-jason-staples).

Comment: Can you edit your question and specify Windows Server version?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue and we opened a Microsoft Case. They ended up deleting the .TMP file extension exclusion and setting it up again. That resolved our issue.

Comment: If you have multiple concurrent writers consider swapping DFS-R for something else, think about clustered SMB3 file share.