# WMI service not working properly

Tags: windows-server-2012, wmi, dfs

I'm Having an issue with WMI, which seems to also affect DFS. I've tried rebuilding the repository, but it's still giving me the same error.

Here's what DFS health report showing:

```
  SRV-FS02   (2 errors)    (View Server Details) 
  Cannot access the local WMI repository.  
  The DFS Replication service is stopped.  

  WIN2K8R2SRV   (1 error)    (View Server Details) 
  Communication errors are preventing replication with SRV-FS02.  


 WARNINGS  (1 server with warnings)(Show All)
 SRV-FS02   (1 warning)    (View Server Details) 
 Reference member returned no replicated folders.
```

Restarted DFS and now there are different errors:

```
SRV-FS02   (3 errors)    (View Server Details) 
Cannot access the local WMI repository.  
Registration failed for the DFS Replication service providers.  
The DFS Replication service is stopped.  

WIN2K8R2SRV   (1 error)    (View Server Details) 
Communication errors are preventing replication with SRV-FS02.
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you run wmi queries?  Anyone fudge with the permissions to WMI?  What have you already checked/researched/tried?

Comment: I'm a bit lost, I'm not sure how to check. I've now rebooted the machine after trying to register, and the only error I am getting is the Registration failed for the DFS Replication service providers error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DFS: File randomly missing?](http://serverfault.com/questions/742909/dfs-file-randomly-missing)